# Compare dates , one table, mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to prepare query which should give a information about customer status ( 1 - new customer, 0 - old customer). The criterias are very simple, the new customer is company with starts cooparate with us or company which start again cooperate with us ( last two year without any transactions( without current year from table) )

Table Customers:

```
CustNo     Year
----------------
610         2013
610         2016
610         2017
610         2019
61000333    2018
61000333    2019
61002463    2013
61002463    2014
61002463    2017
61004504    2013
61004504    2014
61004504    2015
61004504    2016
61004504    2019
```

Table Customers should look like this:

```
CustNo     Year      Status
---------------------------
610         2013        1
610         2016        1
610         2017        0
610         2019        0
61000333    2018        1
61000333    2019        0
61002463    2013        1
61002463    2014        0
61002463    2017        1
61004504    2013        1
61004504    2014        0
61004504    2015        0
61004504    2016        0     
61004504    2019        1
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `LAG`?

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want `lag()` with a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(year) over (partition by custno order by year) >= year - 2
             then 0 else 1
        end)
from t;
```